# how to solve BuildContexts across async gaps error flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I am facing this issue and didn’t know what to do here

```
showSnackbar(
        context,
        text: StatusCodes.absenceCancelResponse[statusCode],
        color: Colors.green,
      );

      class StatusCode
      {
        static Map<int, String> absenceCancelResponse = {
              0: "Absence Request Canceled Successfully",
              1: "Error Cancelling Absence Request",
         };
      
      }
```

Everything working fine but I am annoyed by this warning

```
Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps
```

Comment: could you please add StatusCode class too?

Comment: static Map<int, String> absenceCancelResponse = {
   0: "Absence Request Canceled Successfully",
   1: "Error Cancelling Absence Request",
   };

Comment: I mean please update you question and add the full code inside StatusCodes().

Comment: i add the Status code class and code init. status code is the code we recieved from server. Everything working fine only i want to get rid of this annoying yellow line (i am using intelliJ idea)

Comment: Present the code before and after you run the code `showSnackbar(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered a numerous times here. Just search for it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=BuildContexts+across+async+gaps

In short. Use a StatefulWidget. Before the warning, check if the widget is mounted. Do this using `if (mounted) { ... }` Put the lines where you get the warning inside the curly brackets `{ }`

### Update with Flutter 3.7.0

A `StatefulWidget` is no longer necessary. In a `StatelessWidget` you can now use `context.mounted`

Answer (score -1):

You need to call code with .then(){}, Which you are using after async code in app.

For ex.,

```
await provider.getData().then(){
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
}
```