# Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps - where does the mounted property come from?

Tags: flutter

How to rewrite this to awoid `Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.` warning.

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final isRapportExist = await bloc.isRapportExist();

    if (isRapportExist) {
      return;
    }

    bloc.submitRapport();
    Navigator.pop(context, true); //Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
  }
},
```

In such cases usully `mounted` property used, but where it comes from?

```
if(!mounted) return; //Undefined name 'mounted'.
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve BuildContexts across async gaps error flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527600/how-to-solve-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps-error-flutter)

Comment: mounted is in State, or if you're in newer flutter, also in BuildContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a property of the State class - which your State extends.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can access it from  context (`BuildContext`).

```
if(!context.mounted) return;
```

Comment: this line also produces that warning

Comment: well kinda strange, how about `if(context.mounted){Navigator....}`

Comment: i think [`context.mounted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/mounted.html) came on v3.7

Comment: It happened when I referenced context outside the widget class when I passed context as a parameter. Now context.mounted accessible even in stateless widget.